# How to update multiple documents in mongodb using one query from an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following array of objects...

```
[
    {
        _id: 'dfjkldsjfkldjas',
        name: 'will'
    },
    {
        _id: 'fdsfdakjdhfaskh',
        name: 'bob'
    },
    {
        _id: 'fdsfdasfdfewrfq',
        name: 'tom'
    }
]
```

Is there a way to search a mongodb collection for documents that match these _id's and then $set the name in the document all in one query? Maybe using updateMany?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for updating bulk data

```
 const data = [
        {
            _id: 'dfjkldsjfkldjas',
            name: 'will'
        },
        {
            _id: 'fdsfdakjdhfaskh',
            name: 'bob'
        },
        {
            _id: 'fdsfdasfdfewrfq',
            name: 'tom'
        }
    ]
    const bulkData = data.map(item => (
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: item._id },
                update: { $set: { name: item.name } },
                upsert: true 
            }
        })
    );
await db1.bulkWrite(bulkData, { ordered: false, upsert: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `bulkWrite` to achieve this. First map your array and transform the data like so:

```
const data = [
    {
        _id: 'dfjkldsjfkldjas',
        name: 'will'
    },
    {
        _id: 'fdsfdakjdhfaskh',
        name: 'bob'
    },
    {
        _id: 'fdsfdasfdfewrfq',
        name: 'tom'
    }
]

const bulkData = data.map(item => (
  {
     updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: item._id },
        update: { $set: { name: item.name }}
     }
  })
);
```

Then you use the method `bulkWrite` to save the multiple data.

```
db.yourCollection.bulkWrite(bulkData);
```

You also don't have to use the same DB operation for every entry, you can use different ones on the same bulk like `deleteOne`, `replaceOne`, `insertOne`, etc.

You can check more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/